# Select only records where domain based on user "permission"

Tags: javascript, angular, express, sequelize.js

Hello everyone I'd like to get some tips on how to solve my problem.

I got table where I stores user details like:

> ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME EMAIL, PASSWORD, ROLE, DOMAIN

also got table named Aliases where I got

> ID, DOMAIN_ID, DOMAIN, DESTINATION

In user table role means admin, moderator, user etc. and Domain for example is aaa.pl, bbb.pl. Also Aliases table got domain like aaa.pl, bbb.pl

I want to select from table only aliases where the domain is the same as assigned to the user.
So user X can sees only aliases Where is the same domain.

backend

This is my controller

```
public async aliasesListByDomain(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
        const { domain } = req.params;
        const aliasesListByDomain = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM virtual_aliases WHERE domain= ?', [domain]);
        if (aliasesListByDomain.length > 0) {
            res.json(aliasesListByDomain);
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({ message: "Alias doesn't exists" });
        }
    }
```

There is how I authenticate user

```
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    }
  })
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
          expiresIn: 1440
        })
        res.json({ token: token })
      } else {
        res.send('User does not exist')
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
})
```

And now I have problem with my frontend.

This is my Service where I get all aliases ( no matter of domain )

```
getAliases(): Observable<Alias> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/aliases`);
  }
```

and there is my component where I get all Aliases

```
 getAliases() {
    this.aliasesService.getAliases().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.alias = res;
        console.log(this.alias);
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }
```

Now how can I select only aliases based on users permission.

I tried something like this:

Service

```
getAliasesByDomain(domain: string): Observable<Alias> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/aliases/${domain}`);
  }
```

This is my auth service

to login

```
public login(user: TokenPayload): Observable<any> {
    const base = this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate`, user);
    const request = base.pipe(
      map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.token) {
          this.saveToken(data.token);
        }
        return data;
      })
    )

    return request;
  }
```

and UserDetails

```
 public getUserDetails(): UserDetails {
    const token = this.getToken();
    let payload;
    if (token) {
      payload = token.split('.')[1];
      payload = window.atob(payload);
      return JSON.parse(payload);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Should I in my component get **usertoken** then `JSON.parse()` it and get domain
details from logged user? Then send it to api?

What is best solution for this?

-Edit
I did something like this:

```
 private getToken(): string {
    if (!this.token) {
      this.token = localStorage.getItem('usertoken');
    }
    return this.token;
  }
  getAliasesByDomain(){
    const token = this.getToken();
    let user;
    if (token) {
      user = token.split('.')[1];
      user = window.atob(user);
      user = JSON.parse(user);
      console.log('user z from getAliasesByDomain: '+user.domain);
      this.aliasesService.getAliasesByDomain(user.domain).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.alias = res;
        },
        err => console.error(err)
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: First authenticate user and gets all tokens, then based on logged in user select data of table based on domain of that selected user. So for aliases table when you request data to api return only domain specific values from api side. and , if you cant  not want to go api side then in angular filter data based on domain like `this.aliases = data.filter( domain => domain === this.userDomain )`

Comment: so I should get usertoken inside my component?

Comment: Yes, You can. and you need to verify user token from server side too. So, that token never gets miss used else where.

Comment: can you check my edit? I am getting domain from user.